# Do you have to use worker pools in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

I have a server I am creating (a messaging service) and I am doing some preliminary tests to benchmark it.  So far, the fastest way to process the data is to do it directly on the process of the user and to use worker pools.  I have tested spawning and that is unbelievable slow.

The test is just connecting 10k users, and having each one send 15kb of data a couple of times at the same time(or trying too atleast) and having the server process the data (total length, headers, and payload).

The issue I have with worker pools is its only fast when you have enough workers to offset the amount of connections.  For example, if you have 500k, or 1 million users, you would need more workers to process all the concurrent data coming in.  And, as for my testing, having 1000 workers would make it unusable.

So my question is the following:  When does it make sense to use pools of workers?  Will there be a tipping point where I would have to use workers to process the data to free up the user process?  How many workers is too much, is 500,000 too much?

And, if workers are the way to go (for those massive concurrent distributed servers), I am guessing you can dynamically create/delete as you need?

Any literature is also appreciated!

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe worker pools are not the best tool for your problem. If I were you I would try using Jay Nelson's [epocxy](https://hex.pm/packages/epocxy), which gives you a very basic backpressure mechanism while still letting you parallelize your tasks. From that library I would check either concurrency fount or concurrency control tools.

Comment: I did not switch over to those yet, but I am running into issues when I connect 15-30k+ users at once on the erlang server.  Ill get a {error, closed} (most likely because of slow handshake) on the client who is doing the blasting.  Should I shy away from ssl_accept, and roll my own?